# Code in Command prompt doesn't work in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The code below does what I want when I execute it in the command prompt but not when I put it in a .bat file and try to execute it:

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b *.csv') do for /f "tokens=*" %b in (%a) do echo %b,%a >> all.csv
```

What am I missing.  Also is there a way to have it do exactly what it does without displaying every step in the loop in the command prompt window.  Excuse me I am a newbie!

Answer (score 2):

In batch files - as opposed to at the command prompt - `for` variables require **two** %% signs, e.g. `%%a`.

To turn off echoing of commands as they're being executed, place the following line at the top your batch file: `@echo off`

Note that prepending `@` is an ad-hoc way of suppressing command echoing; in this case it is used to prevent `echo off` itself from being echoed.