# Why does my for /r command not run in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I found the following code that searches all subfolders of the source folder for `.mobi` files, and moves them to another folder:

```
for /r "c:\my\source folder" %i in (*.pdf) do copy "%~fi" "c:\my\destination folder\%~nxi"
```

Running it directly in Command Prompt works great, but adding it to my batch file fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In batch files, your for variable needs two `%` symbols.

Comment: In Batch We Use double quotation...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code in Command prompt doesn't work in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070963/code-in-command-prompt-doesnt-work-in-batch-file)

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [Works in Command Prompt but not in BAT-file or CMD-file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50530157/995714), [for /f is not working in .bat file but it works with command prompt in windows 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32223634/995714), [Why does FOR loop command not work in a batch file which works on Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21431109/995714)