# Works in Command Prompt but not in BAT-file or CMD-file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

Due to problem with WINDOWS DEFENDER I need do the following:

```
for /r "%appdata%\..\Local\MyProg\2.0" %D IN ("*MyProgram.exe") DO "%~fD
```

It works perfect in COMMAND PROMPT but not in batch-file or cmd-file - why?

How do I make in a excutable file as a Batch-file or ".cmd"?

Comment: According to the help pages of [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)`/?`: write `%%D` and `%%~fD` instead of `%D` and `%~fD`, resp.

Comment: Second person today who didn't read the first 8 lines of the help file for the `FOR` command.

Comment: Well, the script was made by a friend and he couldn't make it to work. I gave him someinputs and we tried different versions. I thought the problem had to do with admin rights, problems with **"** or **'** , or the * and "%appdata% in the command line input. Since I didn't wrote the script (including FOR-loop), I totally missed that. We tried with double % but we must have missed the 2nd %... 

I didn't see anything in `for /?` about the double %% in a batch-file...

But lessons learned - not to take anything for sure - and double check everything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running `for` loops in a batch file, you need to use an additional `%` in predefined variables. So it should be:

```
for /r "%appdata%\..\Local\MyProg\2.0" %%D IN ("*MyProgram.exe") DO "%%~fD
```

I suggest you read up using the well documented help by running `for /?` from cmdline. You will benefit from it, guaranteed!

Answer (score 1):

A recursive `For` loop already returns the full path, additionally there's already a system variable for the path `%AppData%\..\Local`.

```bat
For /R "%LocalAppData%\MyProg\2.0" %%A In ("*MyProgram.exe") Do "%%A"
```

*Depending upon your needs, it may be worth checking out the `Start` command usage too, `Start /?`. You may find that `Do Start "" "%%A"` is what you needed.*